# Is internal traffic on Google Compute Engine secure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is network traffic using internal ip addresses on Google Compute Engine secure? E.G. is communication between two VMs in different regions over internal (10.X.X.X) addresses really private to my project?

Answer (score 4):

GCE uses a [software-defined networking stack](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2014/04/enter-andromeda-zone-google-cloud-platforms-latest-networking-stack.html). This means that packets in your private network will only be delivered to the intended destination endpoint in your internal network. This is quite different to a traditional "bare-metal"/wired network and resembles authenticated API calls more than simply sending packets out on the wire.